# How to use System.out.println in Java

Tags: java, println

could you help me resolve my problem ?

### I wrote this simple Java program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Something {

     public static void main(String args[]) {

         Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
         char c1,c2;

    c1=s.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
    c2=s.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
     System.out.println(c1);
     System.out.println(c2);
         s.close();
     }   
    }
```

---

When I press `tf` on my keyboard, the following prints on my console:

```
  t
  r
```

What I am looking for is a single-line output, like

```
tr
```

instead of

```
t
r
```

I tried `System.out.println(c1, c2)` but it is not working.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: System.out.println(c1+c2);

Comment: `System.out.print`.

Comment: @SouravSachdeva that wouldn't do what OP wants, because they are chars: it would promote them to ints and add them.

Comment: System.out.println(c1+c2); will return 230 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `print()` method from the `System` static class. Here is the  [Oracle Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) considering the PrintStream class, which is accessed through the `System.out` call (out is a `PrintStream` there).

Here is a working sample:

```
public class Something {
     public static void main(String args[]) {

         Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
         char c1,c2;

         c1 = s.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
         c2=s.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
         System.out.print(c1);
         System.out.print(c2);

         s.close();
     }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.out.print` not `System.out.println`

If you have multiple characters and want to print them in a single line then use the following logic.

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.out.print(char c)` instead of `System.out.println(char c)` the difference between print and println is that println introduce a break line at the end of each output. You also can do a concatenation `System.out.println(char1+""+char2)`

Comment: OP is printing `char`s, not `String`s.

Comment: console gave me output 230

Comment: Try this System.out.println(char1+""+char2); It gave you that output because char also has a numeric representation called ASCII https://www.asciitable.com/